# Как настроить отладку?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, electron

Делаю приложение на [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue). Никак не получается сконфигурировать launch.json для запуска отладки. Вообще проект запускаю командой `yarn run dev` (ну или `npm run dev`). Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно конфиг для vscode написать?

Comment: На левой панели меню, нажимаете вкладку debug. Вверху, нажимаете на dropdown, там будет список Ваших проектов. Нажимаете на пункт "добавить конфигураци(название проекта)" - и настраиваете

Comment: @Дмытрык спасибо, Капитан Очевидность. Я и сам это знаю. Я не знаю что именно в конфиге прописать чтобы отладчик подключался.

Comment: Ну и не по теме.. Вы уверены, что хотите пользоваться electorn-vue? Этот пакет последний раз обновлялся 4 года назад

Comment: @Дмытрык Vue единственный более менее понятный мне JS фреймворк (во многом благодаря офигительной документации на русском). Есть еще какие-то варианты совместить Vue и Electron?

Comment: Ну, я такого не делал.. но думаю.. что ничего сложного совместить Electorn и Vue  - нет.  Правда, возможно, придется использовать Vue-ssr. Но судя по пакетам, которые устанавливаются во electron-vue, там vue-ssr  не используется

Comment: @Дмытрык у меня опыта в JS - 0.0001. Хочется максимально просто. Я только на JQuery писал до этого))) Просто сам для себя пытаюсь выучить Vue и написать небольшую приложуху. Причем именно десктопная мне нужна.

Comment: @Дмытрык просто в этой библиотеке (electron-vue) хоть какая-то базовая структура создана. Когда я пытался создать проект electron и добавить в него Vue структуры не было никакой... И я просто потерялся. Не знал куда пихать компоненты. Слишком сложно.

Comment: https://itnext.io/electron-application-with-vue-js-and-vuetify-f2a1f9c749b8                   
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/desktop-apps-electron-vue-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

У меня такие настройки, для проекта на Electron'e

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Да нет, это не то. Я же говорю - мне надо не электрон сам по себе запускать, а npm. Он там с вебпаком как-то завязан и hot-reload работает... А так как у вас - это наверное надо уже скомпилированное приложение запускать.

Comment: создал приложение electron-vue через эту команду `vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue my-project` . Правда у меня оно не инсталируется - какие-то ошибки, и разбираться пока желания нет. Но суть в другом, команда `npm run dev` - запускает приложение через nodeJs `node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js`. Только, моем случае, я запускаю `main.js`, а Вам надо запустить `.electron-vue/dev-runner.js`

Comment: Прописал как вы сказали, нажал "start debugging", в vscode вроде как началась отладка (появилась панель с отладочными кнопками), но само приложение так и не запустилось.